# Rails shared controller actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am having trouble building a controller concern. I would like the concern to extend the classes available actions.

Given I have the controller 'SamplesController'

```
class SamplesController < ApplicationController
  include Searchable
  perform_search_on(Sample, handle: [ClothingType, Company, Collection, Color])
end
```

I include the module 'Searchable'

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  module ClassMethods
    def perform_search_on(klass, associations = {})
       .............
    end

    def filter
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render 'api/search/filters.json' }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and, despite setting up a route i get the error `'The action 'filter' could not be found for SamplesController'`.

I thought it might be to do with wether I include, or extend the module. I tried using extend but that also gave the same error.

I still need to be able to feed the module some configuration options on a per controller basis. Is it possible to achieve what I am trying to do here?

Any help appreciated, thanks

Comment: You have to write this after extend ActiveSupport::Concern `def self.included(base)
    base.extend(ClassMethods)
end`

Comment: is this not working for you?

Comment: @PardeepDhingra no its not, please can you post a full answer so I can be sure of what you are doing?

Comment: Please check i have posted full answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should pass `actions` to the [`included`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html) block and `perform_search_on` to the `class_methods` block.

```
module Searchable
  extend ActiveSupport::Concern

  class_methods do
    def perform_search_on(klass, associations = {})
       .............
    end
  end      

  included do
    def filter
      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render 'api/search/filters.json' }
      end
    end

  end
end
```

When your `Searchable` module `include` a method `perform_search_on` and the `filter` action.

Comment: what am i missing? undefined method `perform_search_on' for SamplesController:Class

Comment: @rico_mac pass `perform_search_on` to the  `class_methods do...end` like in updated answer.

Comment: thanks, so this works - but, before I accept, could you tell me the variables I create in `perform_search_on` are not available in the included do block?

Comment: it is different scope. `perform_search_on` defined class method on class level, but `filter` it is instance method on object level. Check  http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Concern.html it is very good described with examples all about `concerns`.

Comment: ook, that makes sense, and is there a way to make these variables available to the instance method on the object level?

Comment: @rico_mac it is all about **application desing**, try to imagine how it is should works, with my suggestions =) this is all what i can help you. Happy coding!

Comment: you don't have to wrap 'def filter' in `included do` block

Comment: you can access class scope from instance scope like this: `self.class.perform_search_on`

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the methods from the module `ClassMethods`. That is making them instance methods.

Comment: @cortext but i require the configurations options for each controller i include the module....